# Model Associations and Data Modelling

Tags: php, model-view-controller, database-design, cakephp, data-modeling

I am developing a web app for an art gallery, and I want to check I have set up the data model correctly.

I have a `people` table and an `artists` table. Some of the `people` are `artists` and some are not.

I also have a `products` table and each `product` belongs to one `artist`.

Below is a simplified version of the tables:

```
products
********
id
title
artist_id

artists
*******
id
profile
rating
person_id

people
******
id
first_name
last_name
```

I need to be able to retrieve the name of the artist when performing the `find()` method on the `Product` model.

Have I set up the data model correctly and if so what is the best way to retrieve the artist's name without getting lots of unwanted data?

Comment: What's the purpose of the "people" table? What's the role of the people who are not artists in your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use CakePHP's bindModel & unbindModel to build up relations that don't rely on Cake's automagic goodness.

Since you were interested in doing the find on the **Product** model, I'll set out an example that can be called from the **Products** controller:

```
// unbind Artist
$this->Product->unbindModel(array(
  'belongsTo' => array('Artist')
));

// bind Artist & Person using explicit conditions
$this->Product->bindModel(array(
  'hasOne' => array(
    'Artist' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('Artist.id = Product.artist_id')
    ),
    'Person' => array(
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('Person.id = Artist.person_id')
    ),
  )
));

// return the person
$person = $this->Product->find('first', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Product.id' => 1 // or any other condition
  ),
  'fields' => array(
    'Person.first_name',
    'Person.last_name'
  )
));
```

What's happening here?

Firstly, we unbind the **Product** model's relationship with the **Artist** model.

Secondly, we bind the **Artist** and **Person** models by explicitly defining the relationships and disabling Cake's automatic forigenKey connections.

Lastly, we do a 'first' find on the **Product** model and only request the '**first_name**' & '**last_name**' of the **Person**.

Answer (score -1):

Each 'Product' belongs to an 'Artist' and each 'Artist' hasAndBelongsToMany 'Product'
You will also need the following table:

```
artists_products
****************
id
product_id
artist_id
```

http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Comment: Artist 'hasMany' Product. A  'hasAndBelongsToMany' relationship is not required nor the table